# How to handle multiple domain through a single React.js application?

Tags: reactjs, cross-domain, hosting

We need to handle multiple domains (website) from a single react.js app.

**Example** - Suppose we have three domain registered into our database -

1. domain1.com
2. domain2.com
3. domain3.com

All these three domains will point to a single server where a react application is hosted. Inside react application different domain URL should be handled and render accordingly.

We are trying to create website solutions for our users so they can host their profile on their own domain. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: [This](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html) article will be helpful

Comment: did you ever solve this?  looking for same solution